# jqxEditor issue, adds a special character at the end of text

Tags: jquery, html, sql, coldfusion, jqwidget

I am using [JqWidgets Text Editor](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxeditor/index.htm#demos/jqxeditor/defaultfunctionality.htm) on a web application. When I  update and save my data to the database, it automatically adds a "?" at the end. Is there a solution to get rid of this. Please help!

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <textarea id="theDesc" form="confForm" rows="10" cols="62" name="conf_desc" style="display: block; margin : 0 auto; margin-left: 0px;">#conf_desc#</textarea>
```

jQuery

```
    $('#theDesc').jqxEditor({
        height: "250px",
        width: '515px'
    });
```

SQL

```
INSERT INTO CONFERENCES(...,CONF_DESC,...)
VALUES(...,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#attributes.conf_desc#">, ...)
```

On Save this is what i get:
[image]

The '?'s are not there in the form values. They only show up once the description is added into the database.

Comment: Try doing  `<cfdump>` of the form submit. See if the extra `?` is in there. Just a thought, I wonder if you have two form fields with the same name.

Comment: I tried that. None of other other form fields have the same name.

Comment: How are you looking at the data when you see the question marks?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: Are you querying the database outside of ColdFusion?  If you are doing so from ColdFusion, are you simply dumping the results or is there some display code going on?  The general idea is to isolate the problem by first verifying that the question marks really are in your database.

Comment: Can you do a `<cfoutput>#conf_desc#</cfoutput>` and see if the ? is content being passed into the `<textarea>`. We need to know what is being pushed in. I wonder if there is a stray control code in the content going in. I would also try `conf_desc.trim()` just as a quick fix

Comment: @JamesAMohler Thank you! that worked. Well not the trim but Left(mystring, len(mystring)-2) worked!

Comment: I would do a hex dump to see what those last 2 characters are. That should help identify where they came from.

Comment: The issue may be related to `Character Set` which may be causing `BOM` characters to appear. You may try setting `Character Set = utf-8` for the db table. And on cfm page you can try adding `<cfprocessingdirective 
pageencoding = "utf-8"> ` on top of the page. See if it helps.